# HTML: A way to prevent showing href in bottom left Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, href

Is there a way to prevent this to show up at the bottom left of a Google Chrome browser when hovering a  with a href?
http://puu.sh/4lQDA.jpg

Comment: why? do you not use this to check where urls go if its looks dodgy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those things designed to protect users, it cant be controlled by the page being viewed as it would defeat the purpose. A [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/239202/turn-off-the-link-hover-statusbar-in-google-chrome) on super user suggests that it is [not possible](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/FtD7qjochgw).

Comment: It should be in other side because some apps have buttons there, and the user is unable to see this buttons behind the link, is not helpful is annoying, in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it solves your purpose .. but you could use javascript to redirect you to new page instead of using href if you dont want user to see link on statusbar.

```
<p onclick="go2URL('http://puu.sh/4lQDA.jpg')">click here</p>


<script>

function go2URL(url)
{
    var win=window.open(url, '_blank');
    win.focus();
}

</script>
```

Obviously u can use onclick even on any other html container as well .. this is just an example.

I dont think there is any direct way to disable status bar functioning.